# Issues with Ubuntu 22.04LTS and Nvidia Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

My Home rig has 6 OSs loaded, with the same hardware for all of them, so 'Hardware issues' can be ruled out.

NVidia 3060ti graphics card.

Currently, my Ubuntu 22.04 install (standard Gnome desktop) cannot detect my graphics card.  It lists "llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)" instead of the correct GPU. Using any Nvidia Driver limits me to a single screen (I run 3) with low resolution (640x480, I think).  Loading Xorg server at least lets me use all 3 screens, but it still does not correctly identify the GPU.

My 20.04 install had to be rolled back to -515.  And it works.
My 23.04 install crashed pretty badly with the -525 drivers, but after a 'firmware' upgrade, it works, as well.

The 22.04 install WAS working on the -515 driver pack, but I tried out the new -530 drivers, which crashed horribly.  I tried resetting to -515, but no joy.  It still won't recognize my graphics card.

Any ideas?  Any at all?  I am stumped.

I am going to check the other versions to see whether or not they are correctly identifying the gpu.

I first hit this problem when I updated to the -520 series drivers.

Comment: This is from the 23.04 install.  It is running the -525 Nvidia drivers. It recognizes the gpu as such: "NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3060 Ti" in the About page

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 using -515 drivers looks correct (all 3 screens in use) but it is displaying "NVIDIA Corporation" under graphics on the About screen.

Comment: @karel, no it does not

Comment: My 22.04 Unity install (yes, I know.  Laugh if you must) is running -515, and displays "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti/PCIe/SSE2".  It would seem weird to me that this issue would be limited a specific release.  But I know now it is not specific to 22.04

Comment: Please do not use comments for info that belongs in the question. All this info needs to be added to the question and not in comments.